# build knowledge in English

Tags: sentence-construction, word-request

how's it going?

Consider this hypothetical scenario:
John moved to the US at a fairly young age and when he moved back to his home country he found it hard to communicate with the locals on matters relating to his expertise (he's a medical doctor btw). He had to resort to "Chinglish" from time to time when talking about medical stuff. For every English jargon he almost always failed trying to find a corresponding term in Chinese.

Given all I just said, how would you describe his situation ***using the following construction***?

Million thanks.

> His body of knowledge about medicine was ...

Comment: It is not John's knowledge of medicine that is the issue, but his limited knowledge of medical Chinese.

Comment: There may also be individual words that are "borrowed" into Chinese. If a process or drug or something is invented and named in one country, the same word may be used in other countries. But it may be given a local pronunciation. So "Chinglish" might actually be correct, at least some of the time.

Comment: His body of knowledge about medicine was deep, but his medical Mandarin was limited.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I wouldn't use that idiom at all. The term '*body of knowledge*' normally refers to the complete body of understanding on a particular subject. Evidently, some use it in connection with an individual's knowledge, although I've never encountered it personally, and [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20body%20of%20knowledge%2C%20my%20body%20of%20knowledge%2C%20his%20body%20of%20knowledge&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20body%20of%20knowledge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmy%20body%20of%20knowledge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chis%20body%20of%20knowledge%3B%2Cc0) demonstrates just how little it is used with a possessive pronoun in comparison to the definite article. I would think that an individual's 'body of knowledge' would encompass *all* their personal knowledge, not just that of a particular subject like medicine. I would just refer to *his medical knowledge*.

There are the words 'anglocentric' (or 'anglophonocentric') which means centred around English, or the English language. It isn't a well-known word, but it would give you a succinct sentence:

> His medical knowledge was anglocentric.

To ensure you are understood, it might be best to simply say:

> His medical training had been in English.

Comment: Thank you, @Astralbee, for your detailed explanation. Based on your suggestions, I am wondering: would it be okay if I say something like "his medical knowledge was built in English"?

Comment: @Underwood Yes, I'd understand that. There's no single right or wrong answer, and probably various ways you could express it.